# How to get the index of the longest common substring?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

The task is to find the index of the longest common substing in the initial two strings, for example for two strings `'money'`, `'working for food not maney'` will be 2 for the first string and 20 for the second one.

Current code for getting just the longest substring is below. How to modify the function below to get the index of the longest substring in the initial strings:

```
def get_len_long_substr(str1, str2):
    substring = ''
    len_str1 = len(str1)
    if len_str1 > 0:
        for i in range(len_str1):
            for j in range(len_str1 - i + 1):
                if j > len(substring) and all(str1[i:i + j] in x for x in [str1, str2]):
                    substring = str1[i:i + j]

    return len(substring), substring
get_len_long_substr('money', 'working for food not maney')
3, 'ney'
# Target index is 2, 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the second index should be 20? I think it should be 23...

Modify your code like below if I am right

```
def get_len_long_substr(str1, str2):
    substring = ''
    len_str1 = len(str1)

    if len_str1 > 0:
        for i in range(len_str1):
            for j in range(len_str1 - i + 1):
                if j > len(substring) and all(str1[i:i + j] in x for x in [str1, str2]):
                    substring = str1[i:i + j]

        idx1 = str1.index(substring)
        idx2 = str2.index(substring)

    return idx1, idx2, len(substring), substring
```

Comment: you right about 23. Really nice approach with str.index - thank you)